# How to install GKrellM Background Changer in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: desktop-background

I have installed GKrellm on my laptop to display the status of capslock/numlock leds (as there is no physical led for numlock). When looking for information on GKrellm, I found that a plugin called GKrellM Background Changer has been developped that seems more simple than Variety that I am currently using. However it is not listed in the plugins available through Synaptic.

The link for this plugin is : http://www.bender-suhl.de/stefan/english/comp/gkrellmbgchg.html

I can dowload the files listed there, but not install them by following the procedure shown on the site.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

1) I downloaded the plugin from the link to my Desktop and I extracted it there.

2) In a console:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
```

It's necessary for compiling with make.

3) Change into the new directory and make:

[image]

4) Copy **gkrellmbgchg.so** to ~/.gkrellm2/plugins:

[image]

[image]

5) Close and launch GKrellM and, in its Configuration Options -> Plugins, "Enable" "Background Changer". Finally, click in OK:

[image]

Comment: Pity that my reputation is not sufficient to vote for you ! I managed to install the plugin with your good explanation.

Comment: But you can mark the question as answered. Can't you?